# DBT - compiled/run files not created in target-path

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to debug a DBT project I've created.

I used to be able to take the compiled\run files from under target folder.

Now for some reason it remains empty after running.

I've tried:

- Running dbt clean and running again.
- Removing target-path: "target" from dbt_project.yml (Which shouldn't make a difference as I'm using the default folder).

Yet it doesn't seem to work.

The problem is only for one specific DBT project. Other projects create compiled files as expected.

Comment: What dbt version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for dbt 1.5 something has changed regarding the `target-path`, see [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/target-path#configuration):

"As of dbt version 1.5, setting the target-path in the dbt_project.yml is deprecated. Backward compatibility is still supported in 1.5 but will be removed in a future update. Migrate to the CLI flag or environment variable methods to avoid potential errors or disruptions."

This should not yet have a direct effect.
However, I've also realized that there has been a behavior change within dbt that has a direct effect on the `target/` path and is not (as clearly) documented. Namely, the target path will be created in the folder from which you run `dbt run` / `dbt compile`. This might diverge from your dbt folder, if you are invoking `dbt` from a parent folder. For example, I call `dbt run --profiles-dir dbt/ --project-dir dbt/` from the root folder of my project. Before, the target folder would be then created under `dbt/target/`. Now, it is created in the root folder `target/`. Maybe you are dealing with this?

Comment: "the target path will be created in the folder from which you run" - I also got caught out by this. A more intuitive behavior IMO would be to always create the target folder (whatever you choose to call it) in the project root.